# Why won't abs() in java work?

Tags: java, syntax

I have always had a question about [java.lang.Math](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html): (It might by very basic)

Why do I have to `Math.abs(-100)` and can't to `abs(-100)`?

I figure that `Math` is a class. And `abs` is a static method. But why can I not simply import `java.lang.Math` and use `abs(-100)`?

Comment: you can if you use `import static java.lang.Math.*;`

Comment: @Stultuske .. my comment was to another comment, that was deleted now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *can* import all the methods in `Math`:

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;
```

or just the one method you want:

```
import static java.lang.Math.abs;
```

Normal imports just import *classes*, making that class available via its short name.

Comment: I read somewhere static imports were bad coding practice in Google...:)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `import static` instead of `static import`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But .. How do I read a static import? Normally static means, that something exists without an instance. How does this apply for imports?

Comment: And @JonSkeet: Please edit your answer: `static import` wont work. I needs to be ´import static´

Comment: @ChristianHenkel: You should read it as "import these static members of types". See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.3

Answer (score 3):

`abs` is a `static` method and in order the compiler knows where it's defined, you have to specify the class (in your case - `Math`).

Note that you could do a `static import` on `Math.abs` and then you'd be able to just do `abs(-100)` instead of `Math.abs(-100)`. In this case you'll have to add an `import` statement like this one:

```
import static java.lang.Math.abs;
```

Note also that in Java, unlike JavaScript and PHP, there aren't any public *functions*, which is why `import` statements are important.

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.Math is statically imported in every Java Class.

```
static import java.lang.Math;
```

Every class of the java.lang package is imported that way.

Answer (score 0):

As you know everything in java is within the class. So their can be only two alternatives.

> Static Function and 
>   Non Static Function

And `java.lang.Math` is a utility library. Creating object of this is not worth for you. so Java guys created all the functions static in this library.

And for your question you can call a member function directly if and only if they are member of same class.